# Expressing a simple declarative proof about exponents in Isar

Tags: isabelle

I'm attempting to write a simple proof about integer exponents in isar.

I've written the argument I want to make in the commented area, but I'm having a very hard time figuring out how to express it. I've been studying `src/HOL/Int.thy` but I either can't find an example proof along these lines or don't understand what I'm looking at yet. :)

```
theory Exponents
imports Main
begin

lemma rMulComm: "(a*b ::int) = (b*a ::int)"
by (rule Groups.ab_semigroup_mult_class.mult.commute)

lemma rExpMul: "((a^b)^c ::int) = (a^(b*c) ::int)"
by (rule Int.zpower_zpower)

theorem HELP: "((a^b)^c ::int) = ((a^c)^b :: int)"
  (*  0.  (a^b)^c 
      1.  a^(b*c)   by rExpMul
      2.  a^(c*b)   by rMulComm
      3.  (a^c)^b   by rExpMul   *)
end
```

This isn't a homework assignment, btw. I'm not in school. :)

**update**: my final version, based on Alexander's answer, below:

```
theorem "((a^b)^c ::int) = ((a^c)^b :: int)"
proof -
  have  "(a^b)^c = a^(b*c)" by (simp only: rExpMul)
  hence "   ...  = a^(c*b)" by (simp only: rMulComm)
  thus  "(a^b)^c = (a^c)^b" by (simp only: rExpMul)
qed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue has to do with the types of `b` and `c` in the theorem `HELP` as well as in the lemma `rExpMul`: the exponent for the operator `^` is a natural number. Therefore `rMulComm` specified for integers cannot be used to prove the theorem. After restating it for natural numbers

```
lemma rMulComm: "(a * b :: nat) = (b * a :: nat)"
```

the proof proceeds immediately:

```
theorem HELP: "((a^b)^c ::int) = ((a^c)^b :: int)"
proof -
  have "(a ^ b) ^ c = a ^ (b * c)" by (simp only: rExpMul)
  also have "… = a ^ (c * b)" by (simp only: rMulComm)
  finally show ?thesis by (simp only: rExpMul)
qed
```

and can be shortened to just `by (simp only: rExpMul rMulComm)`.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you! I was shooting for an ultra-explicit, step-by step proof but just didn't couldn't figure out how to put the syntax together. I wound up going with the updated version above after you showed me the way. :)